# React Native Security Shield like PayTM

Tags: react-native, paytm

I am making an app in react-native where I want to set security shield as PayTM app, PayTM app has a feature wherein if you have the device lock set (PIN, Password, etc), it sets the app lock to the same PIN / Password.

I can get the information whether the pin is set or not using the react-native-device-info package, and basis that I can show the lock screen, but how do I validate the pin entered by the user matches with the device lock or not.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use package [react-native-biometrics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-biometrics) which provide app security same as your device lock have

Comment: This won't work, as there is no option for PIN / Password, and I want it to match with the device lock. Refer PayTM app.

Comment: react-native-biometrics provide fallback option if biometric is not available, So if a device does not have touchId or faceId then it will ask for password